How much tolerance should be placed between a stationary axle and pulley for a 3d printer?
I'm working on a DIY coreXY 3d printer, and, as such, I have stationary axles with pulleys mounted on them. I was wondering how much tolerance should be between the bore of the pulley and the axle to have a good spin but eliminate wobble.

I would make the bore and shaft both oversize and machine to match to give the tolerance required.
